# Show Modal on AngularJS $httpProvider: responseError

Tags: ajax, angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-scope

We need to hookup a `Modal` with a generic message on our failed `Ajax` calls in `AngularJS`.

i was able to intercept the error on the `app.config` part, but from there i am unable to import the `$modal` or the `$scope` to show the modal. What i got working so far is creating a function on my global scope and add the opening of the modal in my `app.run`:

```
var showGeneralException = function () { };

var app= angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.run(function ($rootScope, $modal) {
    showGeneralException = function () {
        var exceptionModel = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'generalException',
            controller: 'exceptionModals',
        });
    };
});

app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q) {
        return {
            'responseError': function (rejection) {
                showGeneralException();
            }
        };
    });
});
```

When i perform it this way a modal opens but i get a not found exception in my modal and following errors in my debug console:

```
TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'data': object is null or undefined 
LOG: WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once. 
LOG: WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once. 
LOG: WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.
```

Comment: 1st thing you need to load angular only once

Comment: It only gets loaded again because of the function. I only initiate 1 app